# Mysql cluster Vs basic Mysql db setup(not cluster)

Tags: mysql, cluster, mysql-replication, mysql-cluster

Why mysql cluster requires more ram as compared to  basic mysql db setup (no cluster)?

What is the ideal ram requirement for a mysql cluster with 2 mysql servers on 2 different hosts ?

Comment: I tried mysql cluster and it was terribly slow compared to MyISAM engine. I tested it on a reasonably powerful machine with 2GB or more. After this test, I setup mysql replication instead. I hope someone else may have had a better experience!

Answer (score 0):

One of the strengths of MySQL Cluster is that it can be run on commodity hardware and has no unusual requirements in this regard, **other than for large amounts of RAM, due to the fact that all live data storage is done in memory.**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-cluster-overview-requirements.html

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct experience related to MySQL cluster, but I believe it's due to data caching (aggresively). Theoritically, by caching you anticipate locality pattern i.e one tends to access certain subset of data over and over again, so it makes sense to cache it in local node.

So how much? I believe there's no real threshold. Ram it as much as you can... 2 or 4 Gigs I guess is the reasonable amount..or more if you have bigger data set.

regards,

Mulyadi
blog: the-hydra.blogspot.com